# Buggy Xlib window manager destroys contextual menus

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm writing a minuscule window manager using Xlib. So far, it does all I expected. However, it has a bug, where contextual menus in Chromium disappear. This starts to happen immediately after closing a Chromium notification window and stops happening randomly afterward. I tested with other window managers (OpenBox, JWM) and Firefox (in Firefox, the menus disappear as soon as the mouse pointer enters them, regardless of notifications having been shown before). The only window manager where this also happens is `twm`.

Given that other major window managers don't behave like this, I understand it is a bug in mine. So my question is: what am I doing wrong?

---

*Edit: For some reason, if I open a link with `Ctrl + Left Click`, the menus will reappear correctly, until I go fullscreen or a notification shows up.

---

Here's the code of the window manager:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define strtok(s)   XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XStringToKeysym(s))
#define grab(m, k)  XGrabKey(dpy, strtok(k), m, r, 1, 1, 1)
#define map(k, c)   if (e.xkey.keycode == strtok(k)) { c; continue; }

int main () {
  Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
  Window r = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
  XEvent e;

  XSelectInput(dpy, r, SubstructureNotifyMask|SubstructureRedirectMask);
  grab(Mod4Mask, "q");
  grab(Mod4Mask, "Left");
  grab(Mod4Mask, "Right");
  grab(Mod4Mask, "Return");
  grab(Mod4Mask, "space");

  while (!XNextEvent(dpy, &e)) {
    if (e.type == KeyPress) {
      map("q",      XKillClient(dpy, e.xkey.subwindow););
      map("Left",   XCirculateSubwindowsDown(dpy, r));
      map("Right",  XCirculateSubwindowsUp(dpy, r));
      map("Return", system("xterm &"));
      map("space",  system("chromium &"));
    }

    if (e.type == ConfigureRequest) {  /* Nasty hack that "works". I'm sure this is wrong. */
      XMoveResizeWindow(dpy, e.xconfigure.window, 0, 0, 1920, 1080);
      XMapWindow(dpy, e.xconfigure.window);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question according to "[ask]"?

Comment: @the busybee, edited accordingly.

Comment: There’s a whole lot more to a WM than simply monitoring a few events. Especially when it comes to some of the ways in which client applications signal their intentions to the WM. Have you looked at the code for any existing WMs to get an idea of how to handle window-specific requests?

Comment: `#define strtok(s)   XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XStringToKeysym(s))`?  `strtok()` is a [standard C function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.8).  At best, using that name is confusing,.  At worst you screw up some parenthesis and wind up calling the function instead of getting your macro expansion.

Comment: @Dúthomhas, I know a conventional window manager does a lot more. However, I have not made use of most of those features progressively through the years, and this one covers everything I need. Yes, I have browsed through the code of several window managers: Openbox, ratpoison, dwm, to name a few. My confusion arose because they implement things differently.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, you got me on that one. I'm using this little thing to learn C on the way as well. That said, I'm pretty sure that's unrelated to the issue I described.